# Extract metadata for package component files using Tika

Tags: metadata, apache-tika, text-extraction

I am trying to extract metadata for package component files using Tika at the command line, but I can only seem to get it to output metadata for the containing package file.  Example: test_file.zip contains two files, test1.doc and test2.doc.  I want to get the metadata for test1.doc and test2.doc, but cannot figure out how to do so.

I tried to run this:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -m test_files.zip
```

but that just outputted the Content-Length, Content-Type, and resourceName for test_files.zip.

I also tried to run this:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -h test_files.zip
```

That outputted the HTML for each component file, wrapped in a `<div>` with class ."package-entry", but the metadata tags were again outputted only for the containing package file test_files.zip.  I tried using the -x parameter instead of -h, and no parameter at all, and got exactly the same result.

How do I get the metadata for the component files?  I don't mind parsing the embedded metadata from xhtml but I cannot figure how to get it injected into the xhtml or otherwise outputted.

Any help much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you willing to write some Java code, or do you need to do it all from the command line with the `tika-app` jar?

Comment: Since I don't know Java, I have a strong preference to do it all from the command line.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've said you want to do it with only the `tika-app` jar, your best option is something like

```
# Create a temp directory
cd /tmp
mkdir tika-extracted
cd tika-extracted
# Have Tika extract out all the embedded resources
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar --extract $INPUT
# Process each one in turn
for e in *; do
   java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar --metadata $e
done
# Tidy up
cd /tmp
rm -rf tika-extracted
```

Using Java, you'd be able to register your own [EmbeddedDocumentExtractor](https://tika.apache.org/1.5/api/org/apache/tika/extractor/EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.html) on the ParserContext, and use that to trigger the metadata extraction for each one individually